# react-stomp-hooks useStompClient hook set to undefined on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, stomp, stompjs

I am using the [react-stomp-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stomp-hooks) package to establish a websocket stomp connection with my backend. I have a function component which renders a certain page where I define `const stompClient = useStompClient()` and on component mount I have a useEffect() which is supposed to publish via stomp directly after the first render. Now the issue is that my defined stompClient is undefined when I refresh the page, however on rendering the page for the first time (via routing from another page), everything works smoothly. The exact TypeError is *Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined*. What am I not seeing here? See my code:

```
const SomePage = () => {
  ...
  const stompClient = useStompClient();


  useEffect(() => {
    stompClient.publish({
      destination: `/app/some_destination`,
      body: 'some-string'
    });

    ...
  }, [])
...
}
```

**EDIT1:**

I figured that the `stompClient` is set to undefined since the connection to the backend has to be set up again on page refresh and the `useEffect` is being called before this setup has taken place. So I need a way to trigger the `stompClient.publish()` only after connection establishment but I dont know how to achieve this. My top most `<App/>` component is wrapping everything in a `<StompSessionProvider/>` (see linked package doc) but how can I listen to an established connection of this StompSessionProvider?

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StompSessionProvider
            brokerURL={`${getWebsocketDomain()}/websocket`}
            debug={STOMP => console.log({STOMP})}
            onConnect={() => console.log({STOMP_CONNECT: 'TCP connection successfully established'})}
        >
          <AppRouter />
        </StompSessionProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
const SomePage = () => {
  ...
  const stompClient = useStompClient();


  useEffect(() => {
    if(stompClient.connected) {
       stompClient.publish({
         destination: `/app/some_destination`,
         body: 'some-string'
       });
    }

    ...
  }, [stompClient.connected])
...
}
```